# Page title not showing up, why not?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set the page title by doing something this in my code:  `this.Title = "string";` but it won't show up at all. Image is here for clarity, I guess. The red part is where the text should be.

[image]

Edit: Alright first off sorry for the lack of information but wasn't sure what to show and what not. I'm trying to change the title based on what the name of an item is that I am getting from the message (I don't think the message is being received, I thought it was since this isn't the only one I'm using. looking into it now, thank you guys for that).

message:
`MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ZonePage, string>(this, "loginname", (s, arg) => { name = arg; this.Title = name; });`

xaml markup:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MobileApp.LoginPage">
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#15a4fa">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="50, 0, 50, 50">
        <Image Source="logotext.png" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="25, 20, 25, 20">
        <Entry x:Name="userNameEntry" TextColor="Black" Placeholder="Username" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
        <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsEnabled="True" TextColor="Black" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Switch x:Name="Remember" IsToggled="False" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Text="Remember me" TextColor="Black" Font="18" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Padding="75, 0, 75, 50" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Picker x:Name="picker"  TextColor="White" Title="Select an Identity Source">
            <Picker.Items>
                <!-- Items added dynamically from xaml.cs -->
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Padding="0, 0, 0, 0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Text="Login" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnLogin"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You'll have to post more code than just `this.Title = "string";`...

Comment: @maccettura that's all I do to try this, the whole line of code there is `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ZonePage, string>(this, "loginname", (s, arg) => { name = arg; this.Title = name; });`

Comment: post your xaml markup

Comment: you put a subscription to something you don't write in the question.  Please post your code of publish/subscribe

Comment: @hugo I didn't initially post the subscribtion because it is irrellevant, but maccettura asked for more.

Comment: @MennoK None of us can help you with a screenshot and one line of code out of context.  You'll have to give us something to work with if you want help.

Comment: Are you sure the message is being received, and the parameter is set correctly?  If you're trying to set the title after the page has already been displayed, you might need to execute on the UI thread

Comment: @Jason, Thank you. this was it, if you can post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint in the method that is receiving the message to ensure you get something. If so, modify your code like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ZonePage, string>(this, "loginname", (s, arg) => { 
    name = arg;

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        this.Title = name;
    });
});
```

This will update your UI thread, which is probably needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your page as NavigationPage on App.xaml.cs level, after InitializeComponent:

```
InitializeComponent();

MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably setting the title to the wrong page.
From what I understand from your image you are using a MasterDetail page. 
If I'm correct this MasterDetailPage holds your LoginPage in where you try to change the title. 
But instead of trying to change the title of the LoginPage try to change the title of the MasterDetailPage which holds the LoginPage as Detail.